# EF: mapping class properties to Rows not Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Do you have an idea how to map properties of a class to rows in a table?
Let's have a table [ID, KEY, VALUE].

I would like to have for predefined key values (on attributes for example) mapped properties in a class, with values taken from value column.

EXAMPLE:

**Table**

```
 ---------------------------------
| ID  | Key        | Value        |
 ---------------------------------
| 1   | Name       | Jon          |
 ---------------------------------
| 2   | Surname    | Doe          |
 ---------------------------------
```

**Class**

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Suname { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything in EF to achieve this or do I have to write my own custom code?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map values from column to properties. Thus you have key-value table, then I suggest you to read table content into dictionary.

First, you should have entity with properties which correspond to table column names:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

After you map this entity to your table, you can read all table content into dictionary:

```
var values = context.Foos.ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);
```

Now you can easily get values by keys:

```
var name = values["Name"];
```

You can even use this dictionary as backing store for your properties:

```
public void Bar
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> values = 
         context.Foos.ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.Value);

    public string Name { get { return values["Name"]; } }
    public string Surname { get { return values["Surname"]; } }
}
```

Comment: It is not the case. I would like to have a property mapped to a ROW not a COLUMN.

Comment: @mdzieg you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

This ins't how databases work.  Each row is a seperate entity.  Each column is a seperate attribute of an entity.  If you are using a database just as a key/value pair, then don't use a relational database.  Take a look at a NoSQL option like Riak or MongeDB.  Another option if this is just a single object for configuration, is to use an xml or configuration file.

Right now, I don't understand how in your example you can tie a name and surname together into a total object.  I don't belive it is possible.

Comment: Wanted to keep those settings in DB for consistency. Actually it could be possible. You could point table name and property column in an attribute on class level, and then for each property define its row value. I worked with DB's that had such kind of tables. Will have to write my own code to handle this I suppose.